# Can't get my work to show on the cube

Tags: objects, properties

[image]I'm new to blender and am following a tutorial on youtube about making a nebula in a cube. I have done a lot of work and it's looking really good with my textures and such, so I save the project and go back in another time. Now when I open blender I can't see all my work show up on the cube anymore. I can still see all the texture files and such but the cube and background are just back to default. Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there something I have to press when I go back to blender to make it all show up again. I've started over 3 times now and the same thing keeps happening when I open my save.

Comment: are you sure that you are in Rendered mode? because when you open a file it's always in Solid mode by default

Comment: Rendered mode? when I open I can see all of my texture files and such. If I look at the render image it's still just a default cube or am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: what you show is Solid mode, you can't see any material in this mode

Comment: okay, super newbie question then, how do I go to rendered mode? I've read that you press Shift + z but that just makes the cube transparent and doesn't show the work

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 4 viewport shading modes: *Wireframe / Solid / Material / Rendered*. Use the shortcut <kbd>Z</kbd> to switch from a mode to another.

[image]

*Wireframe* to see the topology of your object, *Solid* to see the same but with a basic grey shade, these 2 first modes are ideal to work and move your objects, use <kbd>Atl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to enable transparency. *Material* to work on your materials, it won't take into account the lightings, so it won't give a good idea of your render. And at last, the *Rendered* mode, which is how you'll see your objects when rendered.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I feel super silly now :D